# Помогите понять где изъян в логике LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `project`.* 
FROM `project` 
      LEFT JOIN `project_to_app`
             ON `project`.`project_id` = `project_to_app`.`project_id` 
WHERE (`project`.`created_by`=2) 
AND (`project_to_app`.`app_id`<>'userapp56g')
```

Имею проблему в понимании построения запроса. Есть 4 таблицы: `project`, `project_to_app`, `app`, `user`. В запросе участвуют только первые две. `project_to_app` - это таблица связей содержащая поля `id`, `project_id`, `app_id`.

Моя задача вывести список проектов, созданных юзером с id=2 (`project`.`created_by`=2), где `created_by` - это ссылка на таблицу `user` в таблице `project`, и не принадлежащих текущему приложению (`project_to_app`.`app_id`<>'userapp56g'), где 'userapp56g' - это id текущего приложения. Запрос мне возвращает пустой ответ, хотя есть два проекта, оба принадлежать текущему юзеру, но связь есть только с одним из них. Помогите понять, где изъян в логике?

Comment: А если для одного проекта существуют 2 записи разных приложений в to_app вас устраивает, что данный проект будет выведен два раза (у вас сейчас именно так) ? А когда связи вообще нет то app_id is null и любое его сравнение даст ложь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изъян в логике в этом месте, что условие `project_to_app`.`app_id` вы накладываете в where - т.е. вы говорите, что вам нужно **возвращать** только те строки, где значение этого поля не соответствует значению. Тут даже смысл left join теряется, так как null поля по определению возвращают false при любом сравнении с фиксированным значением.

А по факту, вам нужно **присоединять** только те строки, где значение этого поля не соответствует значению - поэтому перенесите условие в *on* при присоединении. Вот так:

```
SELECT `project`.* 
FROM `project` 
      LEFT JOIN `project_to_app`
             ON `project`.`project_id` = `project_to_app`.`project_id`
             AND (`project_to_app`.`app_id`<>'userapp56g') 
WHERE (`project`.`created_by`=2)
```